# Adobe AIR Native Extension Game Kit by Vitapoly. How accept invitation?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, game-center, air-native-extension

I’m trying to make the real time game. When the player accepts invitation,  realTimeMatchesController will dispatch an INVITE_ACCEPTED_EVENT event. But realTimeMatchesController.currentMatch is null. And MATCH_MAKER_FOUND_MATCH_EVENT events not dispatches. So the game is stuck at this point.

How to create a match, when an INVITE_ACCEPTED_EVENT is dispatched?

Here is the sample code

```
public function GameCenter()
 {
 if (!GameKit.isSupported)
 {
 return;
 }

_gamekit = GameKit.instance;

_gamekit.addEventListener(GameKit.LOCAL_PLAYER_AUTHENTICATED_EVENT, localPlayerAuthenticated);
 _gamekit.addEventListener(GameKit.LOCAL_PLAYER_NOT_AUTHENTICATED_EVENT, localPlayerNotAuthenticated);

_gamekit.authenticateLocalPlayer();

_gamekit.realTimeMatchesController.addEventListener(RealTimeMatchesController.INVITE_PLAYERS_EVENT, invitePlayersHandler);

_gamekit.realTimeMatchesController.addEventListener(RealTimeMatchesController.INVITE_ACCEPTED_EVENT, inviteAcceptedHandler);

_gamekit.realTimeMatchesController.init();

_gamekit.realTimeMatchesController.addEventListener(RealTimeMatchesController.MATCH_MAKER_CANCELLED_EVENT, matchMakerCancelled);

_gamekit.realTimeMatchesController.addEventListener(RealTimeMatchesController.MATCH_MAKER_FAILED_EVENT, matchMakerFailed);

_gamekit.realTimeMatchesController.addEventListener(RealTimeMatchesController.MATCH_MAKER_FOUND_MATCH_EVENT, matchMakerFoundMatch);

}

// inviter create the match
public function createMatch():void{
 _gamekit.realTimeMatchesController.startMatch(minPlayers, maxPlayers, playerGroup);
}

private function inviteAcceptedHandler(e:InviteAcceptedEvent):void
 {
 // how to start a match here?
 }

 private function matchMakerFoundMatch(e:MatchEvent):void
 {
 // save the match
  _currentMatch = e.realTimeMatch;
 _currentMatch.addEventListener(RealTimeMatch.RECEIVED_DATA_EVENT, dataReceivedHandler);
 if (_currentMatch.expectedPlayerCount == 0)
 {
  startGame();
 }
 }
```